# Movie where people inhale a child in a field?

Tags: story-identification, movie

On a recent (2021) flight, someone several rows ahead of me was watching a movie on their tablet. I was able to see a few scenes, but not in great detail (because small screen was so far away), and I could hear no sound. I would like to know what it was that they were watching.

- The movie looked to be new (as of 2021)
- In one scene a group of people were chasing a child (of about 13 years?) through a field, and when they caught the child they pinned the child down and appeared to be inhaling smoke off of the child, like they were inhaling the child's spirit, or the child themselves.

  - When they inhaled the smoke their eyes would glow.
  - One of the "smokers" was a women wearing an absurd-looking large black bowler hat, like from Abbot and Costello.
  - Another of the "smokers" was a tall thin man that reminded me of Lurch from "The Addams Family".
- There was another girl (also 13 years?) in some other location that appeared to be affected psychically by the "smoking" while it was happening - she was very distraught.
- There was a scene where the woman in the absurd black hat was in the frozen food aisle of a grocery store, and the distraught girl looked in her window and saw the black-hat woman through the glass door of the frozen food freezer, then somehow attacks her psychically.
- There was another scene where someone played by an actor that looked like Ewan McGregor was running something that resembled an AA (Alcoholics Anonymous) meeting.

  - Could have also been Toby Maguire or Jake Gyllenhaal - they have the same basic face shape at low resolution.

Any guesses what this movie is?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is [*Doctor Sleep*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5606664/), the sequel to *The Shining*.

Ewan MacGregor hosts an AA meeting and there's a fairly memorable scene with a kid in a field having his essence drained.

**Warning: NSFW - Horror**

Comment: Turns out the guy I thought looked like “Lurch” actually did play Lurch in the Addams Family movie from the 90’s.

Comment: @SethMMorton Also Lwaxana Troi's servant in TNG